# Having an issue with the code I wrote in the Update loop. Looking for guidance on troubleshooting it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to unity3d and my problem is that the following code doesn't work and I'm looking for help to find out what I'm doing wrong.

```cs
if (enemy.transform.position.x < 1 & enemy.transform.position.z > 1)
{

  transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, moveSpots2[randomSpot2].position, speed * Time.deltaTime);

  if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, moveSpots2[randomSpot2].position) < 0.1f)
  {  
    if (waitTime <= 0)
    {    
      randomSpot2 = Random.Range(0, moveSpots2.Length);
      waitTime = startWaitTime;
    }    
    else
    {
      waitTime -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
```

**What I'm trying to do:**

When the Enemy position is within the range defined by: `enemy.transform.position.x < 1 & enemy.transform.position.z > 1`

The player doesn't move. But, if the Enemy's position is outside of range then the player moves.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Patrol : MonoBehaviour
{
  public float speed;
  public Transform[] moveSpots2;
  public Transform[] moveSpotsP;
  private float waitTime;
  private int randomSpot2;
  private int randomSpotP;
  public float startWaitTime;
  public Transform ball;
  public GameObject enemy;

  void Start()
  {    
    waitTime = startWaitTime;
    randomSpot2 = Random.Range(0, moveSpots2.Length);
    randomSpotP = Random.Range(0, moveSpotsP.Length);
    GameObject enemy = this.GetComponent<GameObject>();
  }

  void Update()
  {    
    transform.LookAt(ball);

    if (enemy.transform.position.x > 0 & enemy.transform.position.z < 0)
    {
      transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, enemy.transform.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    if (enemy.transform.position.x < 0 & enemy.transform.position.z < 0 | enemy.transform.position.x > 0 & enemy.transform.position.z > 0)enemy.transform.position.x < 0 & enemy.transform.position.z > 0)
    {
      transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, moveSpotsP[randomSpotP].position, speed * Time.deltaTime);

      if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, moveSpotsP[randomSpotP].position) < 0.1f)
      {
        if (waitTime <= 0)
        {    
          randomSpotP = Random.Range(0, moveSpotsP.Length);
          waitTime = startWaitTime;
        }    
        else
        {
          waitTime -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
      }

      if (enemy.transform.position.x < 1 & enemy.transform.position.z > 1)
      {   
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, moveSpots2[randomSpot2].position, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, moveSpots2[randomSpot2].position) < 0.1f)
        {    
          if (waitTime <= 0)
          {    
            randomSpot2 = Random.Range(0, moveSpots2.Length);
            waitTime = startWaitTime;
          }   
          else
          {
            waitTime -= Time.deltaTime;
          }          
        }
      }   
    }
  }
```

Comment: In Update you put the game handling code. There you progress the game state. Note that realtime games do not really exist. Instead we just use very, *very*, **very** small turns wich do not wait for user input. We call those "gameticks". Input handling. (non-particle) Physics. That is what belongs here. You have a counter function wich will draw the game state. These two functions play ping-pong in the processor, togeher creating what we call the "game loop"

Comment: Is it possible you have some typos there? In general you shouldn't be using binary comparison `&` but rather use the bool comaprison `&&`. What do you mean by `following code doesn't work` please describe what exactly isn't behaving as expected

Answer (score 0):

In Update you put the game handling code. There you progress the game state. Note that realtime games do not really exist. Instead we just use very, *very*, **very** small turns wich do not wait for user input. We call those "game ticks". A large part (at least 3/4) of the Update function are those game ticks.

You have a counter function wich will draw the game state. These two functions play ping-pong in the processor. They are called interchangeably. Together creating what we call the [game loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_programming#Game_structure).

Input handling. (non-particle) Physics. The game menu logic. That is what belongs here. There are cases where you want to handle stuff but do not want advance the gamestate - stuff like the game being paused. Those belong into update, but usually a bool will lock out progressing the game tick.

The biggest mistakes are usually:

- putting the gametick logic into the Draw function - seriously guys it is 2019. The mistake as bad in teh last millenium and it did not go any better
- accidetally locking the UI updates/input handling behind the gameticks.

Comment: ..... so? Nice explenation but how does it address the question about the [`Update`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) message which is called once every frame representing the described "game tick" ...

Answer (score 0):

The update function is called every frame. Essentially the way all games work is they perform calculations (the calculations depend on what the game is doing) and then based on those calculations they "draw" a frame and display it on the monitor. The faster the computer can perform the calculations and draw the frame is the frame rate, or FPS (Frames per seconds).

Basically, put everything in Update that you need to be calculated every frame of the game. Don't use it if you don't need it though, generally the less calculations you have to perform each frame, the higher the frame rate is.

Usually you want to check stuff like input (so like if a players pressing the shift key etc.) in Update because you want to constantly be checking if the player is pressing shift (or whatever key/input you're checking for)

For stuff that you only need performed on or before the first frame is drawn, use Start or Awake (Awake is like Start, but it's called even earlier).

There's also other methods you sometimes use like OnTriggerEnter (see the documentation).

There's also other variations of Update for different tasks, such as FixedUpdate which you use for physics calculations and LateUpdate which you use for camera movement, but most of the time you'll use update.

Documentation:

```
https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.LateUpdate.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html
```